# How can I change the Voiceover value of a UIButton programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover

I've created a UISwitch in InterfaceBuilder to toggle audio on and off. The switch works fine, but I want to change the value that Voiceover reads out from the current '0' and '1' to 'Off' and 'On'.  My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class AudioStreamTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var controller: EventDetailsViewController!
    weak var audioInterface: EventAudioInterface? { didSet { if self.audioInterface !== oldValue { self.updateUI() }}}
    func updateUI() {}
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.updateUI()
    }

}

class MuteStreamTableViewCell: AudioStreamTableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "MuteStreamTableViewCell"

    @IBOutlet var muteSwitch: UISwitch!

    override func updateUI() {
        self.muteSwitch.isOn = self.audioInterface?.muted ?? false
    }

    @IBAction func switchChanged(_ muteSwitch: UISwitch) {
        self.controller.setMuted(muteSwitch.isOn, on: self.audioInterface)

        if muteSwitch.isOn {
            self.muteSwitch.accessibilityValue = "on"
        } else {
            self.muteSwitch.accessibilityValue = "off"
        }
    }

}
```

Voiceover still speaks '0' and '1'. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: This suggests you may want to try setting `accessibilityLabel` instead: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615181-accessibilitylabel

Comment: When I do that, it changes the string spoken by Voiceover for the label, overriding the label I set in IB ("Mute Switch"). I.e., the spoken label is now replaced with either "on" or "off", while the switch value is still reported as "0" or "1"

Comment: FWIW, VoiceOver is announcing the value for switches to be on/off in my app and throughout the rest of iOS, not 0/1.

Answer (score 9):

## Swift 4.2

I had to subclass `UISwitch` and override `accessibilityValue`.

```
class AccessibilityUiSwitch: UISwitch {
    override var accessibilityValue: String? {
        get {
            return isOn ? "on" : "off"
        }
        set {
            self.accessibilityValue = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was scratching my head for quite some time. This worked like a charm!!

Comment: Works, I also had it read 0 and 1 before.